# How to inject JavaScript using FireBreath

Tags: macos, npapi, firebreath

is it possible to inject javascript inside a web page from a Plug-In made under FireBreath Framework?  i dont want to use safari extensions so I am wondering if using Plug-ins I can do the same or even more than suggest do it with Extensions. Mi idea is to write a function that detects a keyPress event in whatever textbox in the page and then pass the message to a javascript function which communicate with the JSAPI function exposed by the plugin.

thanks for any suggestions or guide.

BTW I am creating the firebreath plug-in to work with Mac OSx platform.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/). You don't get plugins inserted into every page, you have to specifically embed them.

Comment: Ok Georg, great article, I have everything clear now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While you can inject JavaScript into a page from a plugin - just like you could from JavaScript - you'd need to get the plugin embedded into the page.
If you have that kind of control over the page then you won't need a plugin in the first place.

To have control over arbitrary pages that you can't control directly, you need a browser-extension/-addon. [This article](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/) contains more detail on the subject.